# Conversion of type '{ [index: string]: string; }' to type 'T' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other

Tags: typescript

I have the following util for transforming the object with `key: string` values. 
Link to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-enko7

```
const caseObject = {
  prop1: `string`,
  prop: `string`
};

function createSelectorsFromClasses<T>(
  classesConfig: T,
  extraSelectorsConfig?: T
): T {
  const selectorsConfig: { [index: string]: string } = {};

  /* 
  * Also for accessing classesConfig[key] TSLint outputs:
  *TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because 
  expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.   
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'. */
  Object.keys(classesConfig).forEach(key => {
    selectorsConfig[key] = `.${classesConfig[key]}`;
  });

  if (extraSelectorsConfig) {
    Object.keys(extraSelectorsConfig).forEach(key => {
      selectorsConfig[key] = extraSelectorsConfig[key];
    });
  }

  return selectorsConfig as T;
}

const newObject = createSelectorsFromClasses(caseObject);
```

For the `return selectorsConfig as T` TSLint outputs:

```
TS2352: Conversion of type '{ [index: string]: string; }' to type 'T' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.   '{ [index: string]: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

Can you please suggest how to properly:
1. Preserve defined index type for `selectorsConfig`
2. Defined index type for  used for `classesConfig`
3. Return the newly created object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want, right? You was almost there, you just need to make the generic type to satisfy the `selectorConfig` type `{ [index: string]: string }`.

```
const caseObject = {
  prop1: `string`,
  prop: `string`
};

type SelectorConfig = { [index: string]: string };

function createSelectorsFromClasses<T extends SelectorConfig>(
  classesConfig: T,
  extraSelectorsConfig?: T
): T {
  const selectorsConfig: SelectorConfig = {};

  /* 
  * Also for accessing classesConfig[key] TSLint outputs:
  *TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because 
  expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.   
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'. */
  Object.keys(classesConfig).forEach(key => {
    selectorsConfig[key] = `.${classesConfig[key]}`;
  });

  if (extraSelectorsConfig) {
    Object.keys(extraSelectorsConfig).forEach(key => {
      selectorsConfig[key] = extraSelectorsConfig[key];
    });
  }

  return selectorsConfig as T;
}

const newObject = createSelectorsFromClasses(caseObject);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, Pedro. It actually makes sense :-)